# How to make X axis wider in foresplot

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm having trouble widening the x axis of the forestplot. i.e. area inside the red box. I want to increase/zoom-in the plotted area(area inside the red box) without skipping any numbers.
I want it to be wide enough for improved visibility. Any tips on how to expand the mean (95% CI) number lines would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Here are the r codes that I have used to create the above forestplot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(forestplot)
library(dplyr)

Number <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)
group <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B')
labeltext <- c('Altered level of consciousness','Central neuropathy','Fever','Headache','Hypotension','Nausea vomiting','Pallor','Visual changes','Weakness','Altered level of consciousness','Central neuropathy','Fever',
               'Headache','Hypotension','Nausea vomiting','Pallor','Visual changes','Weakness')

mean <- c(0.52,0.88,1.01,0.97,0.55 ,0.99,0.64,0.49,NA,NA,0.04 ,0.1,0.09,0.04,0.04,0.04 ,0.04,NA)
lower <-c(0.39,0.7,0.72,0.59,0.45,0.69,0.44,0.32,NA,NA,0.02,0.04,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.01,0.01,NA)
upper <-c(0.68,1.11,1.43,1.6,0.68,1.42,0.95,0.73,NA,NA,0.11,0.23,0.31,0.09,0.15,0.16,0.17,NA)

df <- data.frame(Number, group, labeltext, mean, lower, upper)


df <- df %>% mutate(est = sprintf("%.2f", mean), .after = labeltext)

clrs <- fpColors(box = "royalblue",line = "darkblue", summary = "royalblue")

tabletext <- list(c(NA, df %>% filter(group == "A") %>% pull(labeltext)),
                  append(list(expression(beta)), df %>% filter(group == "A") %>% pull(est)))

df %>% 
  filter(group == "A") %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(mean = NA), .) %>% 
  forestplot(labeltext = tabletext, 
             col = clrs,
             xlab = "95 CI")


df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  forestplot(title= "test header",
             clip = c(0, 5),
             lty.ci=c(2,3),
             lwd.ci = 1,
             shapes_gp = fpShapesGp(box = c("chocolate1", "aquamarine3") %>% lapply(function(x) gpar(fill = x, col = "#555555")),
                                    default = gpar(vertices = TRUE)),
             ci.vertices = TRUE,
             ci.vertices.height = 0.05,
             boxsize = .1,
             ticks = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex = 5),
             xlab = "mean (95% CI)",
             grid=structure(c(1), gp=gpar(lty=2, lwd=1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential solution to your problem. You can create the range of your `x-axis` by doing this Tthis is just an example. I am not sure what values you want to use).

```
ticks <- c(0.04, 0.2, 1, 2) 
attr(ticks, "labels") <- as.character(ticks)
```

You can add the ticks into your code to change the x-axis like this

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  forestplot(title= "test header",
             clip = c(0, 5),
             lty.ci=c(2,3),
             lwd.ci = 1,
             shapes_gp = fpShapesGp(box = c("chocolate1", "aquamarine3") %>% lapply(function(x) gpar(fill = x, col = "#555555")),
                                    default = gpar(vertices = TRUE)),
             ci.vertices = TRUE,
             ci.vertices.height = 0.05,
             xticks=ticks, # ADDITION
             boxsize = .1,
             ticks = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex = 5),
             xlab = "mean (95% CI)",
             grid=structure(c(1), gp=gpar(lty=2, lwd=1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I really like the idea of pre-defining the x-axis-it is very helpful. Thank you! I like your output too but my R studio still displays it in small scale. Could it be that there is something wrong in my Rstudio settings? What settings should I check?

Comment: In Rstudio, the plots that show up in the "plots" section, typically are very small and not to scale. Try clicking "zoom" to show the full size of the plot. While I was making the graph, I actually thought that you might not have been expanding the graph in your Rstudio because the code that you used to create your original graph actually looked like a pretty decent size in my Rstudio @PrajwalManiPradhan

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I think that I might have messed up my Rstudio settings. I will uninstall and reinstall R studio. Thanks again for the suggesting the Xaxis and confirming that the display from my code looks okay! have a wonderful day ahead!

Comment: No problem. Your original code pretty much made a graph the same size as the image that I posted